# Regular Expression for New line is not working in UiPath

Tags: regex, uipath

I have the following text in a text file, and I wanted to read the 2nd line using regexp in UiPath, a company name (i.e. SOME ANALYTICS).

> INVOICE DETAILS Invoice To:
> **SOME ANALYTICS**
> Invoice#   :   R0264
> Invoice Date: 27/06/20

I have tried following regular expressions on https://regexr.com/ to retrieve the data and it is working fine. But the same expression is not working on UiPath.

`(?<=To:[\n\r]).+`

Comment: Try it like this `(?<=To:\r?\n).+` Or if there might be trailing spaces `(?<=To:\s*\r?\n).+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```cs
(?<=^.*\n).+
```

*Details*:

- `(?<=^.*\n)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a position that occurs right after the first line that ends with an LF char
- `.+` - one or more chars other than an LF char (the second line).

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5E.*%5Cn%29.%2B&i=INVOICE%20DETAILS%20Invoice%20To%3A%0D%0ASOME%20ANALYTICS%0D%0AInvoice%23%20%3A%20R0264%0D%0AInvoice%20Date%3A%2027%2F06%2F20).

Another option is to take out the CR out of the equation and make the regex multiline flag insensitive by replacing `^` with `\A`:

```cs
(?<=\A[^\r\n]*\r?\n)[^\r\n]+
```

This regex matches

- `(?<=\A[^\r\n]*\r?\n)` - a location that is immediately preceded with

  - `\A` - start of string
  - `[^\r\n]*` - zero or more chars other than CR and LF as many as possible
  - `\r?\n` - an optional CR and then LF char
- `[^\r\n]+` - one or more chars other than LF and CR.

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5CA%5B%5E%5Cr%5Cn%5D*%5Cr%3F%5Cn%29%5B%5E%5Cr%5Cn%5D%2B&i=INVOICE%20DETAILS%20Invoice%20To%3A%0D%0ASOME%20ANALYTICS%0D%0AInvoice%23%20%3A%20R0264%0D%0AInvoice%20Date%3A%2027%2F06%2F20).

Comment: Thanks mate. It worked. I am new to this. Could you please suggest any good tutorial!

Comment: @Sudarsh I do not know your level of regex knowledge :) so that I can only suggest doing all lessons at [regexone.com](http://regexone.com/), reading through [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info), [regex SO tag description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) (with many other links to great online resources), and the community SO post called [What does the regex mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean). Also, [rexegg.com](http://rexegg.com) is worth having a look at.

Comment: @Sudarsh Besides, I have started a ["Regex Quickies" Youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCFeq5T-LNtqpVrn_rcJ9hFw), where you can learn more about regex in general.

Answer (score 1):

You can match the line that ends on `To:` and then capture the next line in group 1.

```
^.* To:\r?\n(.+)
```

- `^` Start of the line (in multiline) (Or use `\A` to match start of the whole string)
- `.* To:` Optionally match any character followed by a space and `To:`
- `\r?\n` Match an optional carriage return and a newline
- `(.+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ times any char

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mHICPp/1)

Using `[\n\r]` matches either a newline or a carriage return. If there is a carriage return and a newline, you could also try:

```
(?<=To:\r?\n).+
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3dTo%3a%5cr%3f%5cn%29.%2b&i=INVOICE+DETAILS+Invoice+To%3a%0d%0aSOME+ANALYTICS%0d%0aInvoice%23+%3a+R0264%0d%0aInvoice+Date%3a+27%2f06%2f20)